# Identify a font by extracting vector from a JPEG

Tags: fonts, jpeg, vector-graphics

I'm trying to identify the font used in this graphic.

[image]

Alternatively, is there a way to extract this letter out into a vector graphic form that I could scale up? I have Pixelmator at my disposal.

Comment: If you have more characters to go by, you may be able to use [Identifont](http://www.identifont.com/) or something similar to identify the typeface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [WhatTheFont](http://new.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/), the font is [Winch-Gras](http://new.myfonts.com/fonts/t26/winch/gras/).

Comment: Never knew about that site. Fantastic thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There are various programs that will allow you to create a vector from a file, examples are Illustrator and Inkscape. however, the font is fairly easily identified by uploading the file to [WhatTheFont](http://new.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/), I got [these](http://new.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/results?ch[0]=b&wtfserver=104&id=000051a64d67d3e1000ce2f700007c10&glyphcount=1&imageid=0&x=35&y=39) promising results.

[Winch-Gras](http://new.myfonts.com/fonts/t26/winch/gras/):

[image]

Comment: Don't suppose there's anywhere to get that font for free?

Comment: @Ternary I'm sure there are underground websites that might offer them, but I urge you to consider paying for it. Paying will encourage developers to maintain their developing of great fonts/software.

Comment: Yea for sure, I'm not into stealing. I was just curious, I don't really know much about the font world. Thanks again!

Comment: @Ternary Well, just like software, fonts are licensed and can be either free, trial or commercial.